# Optimising unpacking objects with dynamic keys in TS

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, javascript-objects

I am trying to match some items in two datasets:
usersItems: Record<string, string>[] ,
latestItems: Record<string, string>

I need to consider each item in the usersItems array, and look to see if there is an equivalent attribute in the latestItems object.  Because these have dynamic keys I am having issues unpacking the key value pairs in the usersItems with the required speed.

I have the following code, which works, but will need to improve the performance. I can't see how to leverage the usual map functions with dynamic keys.

I think the line
**for (const [itemId, version] of Object.entries(item))** is the biggest problem, but I could only see this way of deconstructing the keys value pairs into values I can use. There must be a better way...

Any help here would be appreciated:

```
export async function filterItems(
  usersItems: Record<string, string>[] ,
  latestItems: Record<string, string>
): Promise<string[]> {

  const filteredItemsForUser: string[] = [];

  for (const item of usersItems) {
    for (const [itemId, version] of Object.entries(item)) {     
      if (Object.values(latestItems).includes(version)) {
        filteredItemsForUser.push(itemId);
      }
    }
  }
  console.log("filteredItemsForUser: " + filteredItemsForUser);
  return filteredItemsForUser;
}

//usersItems is small 20 entries approx
const usersItems:  Record<string, string>[] =  [
        {"id1": "ID#id1#VERSION#1"},
        {"id2": "ID#id2#VERSION#1"},
        {"id4": "ID#id4#VERSION#2"},
        {"id6": "ID#id6#VERSION#1"},
      ]


//latestItems is large potentially ~5k key value pairs
const latestItems:  Record<string, string> =  {
      "id1": "ID#id1#VERSION#1",   //will match
      "id2": "ID#id2#VERSION#4",   //won't match as latest version is different
      "id3": "ID#id3#VERSION#5",   
      "id4": "ID#id4#VERSION#2",   //will match
      "id5": "ID#id5#VERSION#5",
      "id6": "ID#id6#VERSION#6",   //won't match as latest version is different
    }

filterItems(usersItems, latestItems);
```

This will print `"filteredItemsForUser: id1,id4"`

edit 12/2/24  I have updated the sample data to make the intent clearer.

The values in each of latestItems entries will be unique so I can make into a set first, I like that idea @jcalz.

I had thought I could leverage the fact that the ids were the same to be able to retrieve the item in lastestItems that we need to check, but prob better to make the values into a set first for quick lookup.

Comment: ① You're talking about performance problems but this code doesn't seem to be a [mre] that demonstrates it, so it's difficult for anyone else to test a suggestion before posting as an answer; do you have any way to easily show the problem? ② Could you [edit] the example data to be easier for a human being to parse? Long guid-like strings that only differ in a few characters make it actively harder. ③ Those being said, maybe [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/wX0now) would work for you? If so I could write up an answer; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: "*look to see if there is an equivalent attribute in the latestItems object*" - that's not what `Object.values(latestItems).includes(version)` is doing. Maybe you meant to check `latestItems[itemId] === version`? If you really need to repeatedly check for *all* the values in `latestItems`, use a `Set` instead.

Comment: "*I think the line `for (const [itemId, version] of Object.entries(item))` is the biggest problem*" - no, since each of your `item`s (in `usersItems`) have only a single entry anyway. You may as well write `const [itemId, version] = Object.entries(item)[0];`.

Comment: Your code looks like it's getting all packages where the latest version is used by a user, per user so that the returned array might contain duplicates if the same latest version is used by multiple users. Is that intended?